# Need a code for a button in excel that will insert a new range of cells, including the formulas

Tags: excel, vba, insert, range, formulas

i'm trying to create a database with an undefined number of rooms, where each room includes many finishing materials. So, for the first room, i create a range of cells, from column A row 1 to column Y row 10, with many complex formulas, and i want a button that will automatically copy this set of 10 rows, under them. I know how to create a button, all i need is a  code to get another set of cells predefined with the formulas of the first set. Help! thank you! (sorry for my language, i'm not a native speaker...)

Comment: This sounds like a really good opportunity to use the built-in `Range.Copy` method. Here's a link to the documentation on MSDN, which includes some really helpful examples (by Bill Jelen): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Please post what you've already tried and where it's not working

Comment: well, i will assume that i have not tried any code because i am aware that is above my knowledge power.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code to get started

Sub orginal_set

```
Dim arraySource As Variant ' this is were you will store your sourced data
Dim strPastetab as string ' this is the name of the tab you will paste to.  You can build an appropriate loop to do as many sheets as you want

arraySource = Sheets("sourcesheet").range("A1:Y10") 'fills your array
Sheets(strPastetab).Range("A1:Y10") = arraySource ' paste your array as long as these are the same size their should be no problem
```

End sub

Comment: thanks for the code, but it get me an error somewhere in the last line of code ( Sheets(strPastetab).Range("A1:Y10") = arraySource ). Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range??? I really don't know how to handle with this error.

Comment: post you entire code block it will be easier to help you then